# Two websites in same ASP.NET solution

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, iis, url-rewriting

I have two websites (index.html files) in the same asp.net solution. I have two domains that I want to direct to the correct html file.

This is an angularjs application so I have only one html file per site.

I want all requests for any resources at http://site1.myhostname.com/ to return /index.html.

And I want all requests for any resources at http://site2.myhostname.com/ to return /site2/index.html

Is this possible with configuring web.config and/or dns configuration?

Comment: Assuming I understood - "Solution" doesn't necessarily equate to "IIS Web sites/applications". You could mark each "folder" as it's own IIS "Website/Application" each with its own `host header` (and then handle in DNS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two solution

1. The first one is to have 2 different websites in IIS and use appropriate binding configuration. In this case, each website will have its own folder and resources.

   [image: IIS configuration with 2 websites]

   [image: Binding configuration]

   This is the solution I would recommend.
2. The other solution would be to use the URL rewrite module of IIS.

   You can install it there : http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

   Then in your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>        
      <rule name="Rewrite sub-domain to sub-directory" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
           <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(\w+)\.company\.com" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{C:1}/{R:0}" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

This rule will rewrite all request coming from a subdomain to a subdirectory.

Comment: Before I saw this answer, I went with the second suggestion of using the iis rewrite module.  This module was already being used in the web.config to redirect all requests to the index.html page (single page angularjs application).  I added another rule for the second site and use the HTTP_HOST condition to rewrite the request to be for the correct index.html